# Why is lazy evaluation useful?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I have long been wondering why lazy evaluation is useful. I have yet to have anyone explain to me in a way that makes sense; mostly it ends up boiling down to "trust me".

Note: I do not mean memoization.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Mostly because it can be more efficient -- values don't need to be computed if they're not going to be used. For example, I may pass three values into a function, but depending on the sequence of conditional expressions, only a subset may actually be used. In a language like C, all three values would be computed anyway; but in Haskell, only the necessary values are computed.

It also allows for cool stuff like infinite lists. I can't have an infinite list in a language like C, but in Haskell, that's no problem. Infinite lists are used fairly often in certain areas of mathematics, so it can be useful to have the ability to manipulate them.

Comment: Python has lazily-evaluated infinite lists via iterators

Comment: You can actually emulate an infinite list in Python using generators and generator expressions (which work in a similar way to a list comprehension): http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/genexpr.html

Comment: Generators make lazy lists easy in Python, but other lazy evaluation techniques and data structures are noticeably less elegant.

Comment: I'm afraid I'd disagree with this answer. I used to think that laziness was about efficiency, but having used Haskell a substantial amount, and then switching to Scala and comparing the experience, I'd have to say that laziness matters often but rarely because of efficiency. I think Edward Kmett hits on the real reasons.

Comment: I similarly disagree, while there's no explicit notion of an infinite list in C because of strict evaluation, you can easily play the same trick in any other language (and indeed, in most every lazy language's actual imlementation) by using thunks and passing around function pointers to work with a finite prefix of the infinite structure produced by similar expressions.

Comment: @MarkCidade python can't do things like `fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. Iterators are completely orthogonal to laziness.

Comment: @MarkCidade Well...it can if you teach it how :P https://gist.github.com/3noch/7969f416d403ba3a54a788b113c204ce

Comment: I think this answer is basically wrong. A language like rust, or a language with a JIT can optimize out any call with immutable (or static) inputs/captures that don't end up being returned.
They could even automatically make it work as a lazy evaluation under the hood iff the use of the evaluation ends up being conditional on runtime inputs, but the thing is, that's pretty rare!

Answer (score 78):

I find lazy evaluation useful for a number of things.

**First**, all existing lazy languages are pure, because it is very hard to reason about side effects in a lazy language.

Pure languages let you reason about function definitions using equational reasoning.

```
foo x = x + 3
```

Unfortunately in a non-lazy setting, more statements fail to return than in a lazy setting, so this is less useful in languages like ML. But in a lazy language you can safely reason about equality.

**Secondly**, a lot of stuff like the 'value restriction' in ML aren't needed in lazy languages like Haskell. This leads to a great decluttering of syntax. ML like languages need to use keywords like var or fun. In Haskell these things collapse down to one notion.

**Third**, laziness lets you write very functional code that can be understood in pieces. In Haskell it is common to write a function body like:

```
foo x y = if condition1
          then some (complicated set of combinators) (involving bigscaryexpression)
          else if condition2
          then bigscaryexpression
          else Nothing
  where some x y = ...
        bigscaryexpression = ...
        condition1 = ...
        condition2 = ...
```

This lets you work 'top down' though the understanding of the body of a function. ML-like languages force you to use a `let` that is evaluated strictly. Consequently, you don't dare 'lift' the let clause out to the main body of the function, because if it expensive (or has side effects) you don't want it always to be evaluated. Haskell can 'push off' the details to the where clause explicitly because it knows that the contents of that clause will only be evaluated as needed.

In practice, we tend to use guards and collapse that further to:

```
foo x y 
  | condition1 = some (complicated set of combinators) (involving bigscaryexpression)
  | condition2 = bigscaryexpression
  | otherwise  = Nothing
  where some x y = ...
        bigscaryexpression = ...
        condition1 = ...
        condition2 = ...
```

**Fourth**, laziness sometimes offers much more elegant expression of certain algorithms. A lazy 'quick sort' in Haskell is a one-liner and has the benefit that if you only look at the first few items, you only pay costs proportional to the cost of selecting just those items. Nothing prevents you from doing this strictly, but you'd likely have to recode the algorithm each time to achieve the same asymptotic performance.

**Fifth**, laziness allows you to define new control structures in the language. You can't write a new 'if .. then .. else ..' like construct in a strict language. If you try to define a function like:

```
if' True x y = x
if' False x y = y
```

in a strict language then both branches would be evaluated regardless of the condition value. It gets worse when you consider loops. All strict solutions require the language to provide you with some sort of quotation or explicit lambda construction.

**Finally**, in that same vein, some of the best mechanisms for dealing with side-effects in the type system, such as monads, really can only be expressed effectively in a lazy setting. This can be witnessed by comparing the complexity of F#'s Workflows to Haskell Monads. (You can define a monad in a strict language, but unfortunately you'll often fail a monad law or two due to lack of laziness and Workflows by comparison pick up a ton of strict baggage.)

Comment: While it may be the case that "all lazy languages are pure" is true (I don't know, offhand), it's not that case that all languages that support lazy evaluation are pure. Many languages allow you to signify that something won't be evaluated until a later time.

Comment: Very nice; these are the real answers. I used to think that it was about efficiency (delaying computations for later) until I used Haskell a significant amount and saw that that's really not the reason at all.

Comment: Also, while it's not technically true that a lazy language must be pure (R as an example), it is true that an impure lazy language can do very weird things (R as an example).

Comment: Sure there is. In a strict language recursive `let` is a dangerous beast, in R6RS scheme it lets random `#f`'s appear in your term wherever tying the knot strictly led to a cycle! No pun intended, but strictly more recursive `let` bindings are sensible in a lazy language. Strictness also exacerbates the fact that `where` has no way to order the relative effects at all, except by SCC, it is a statement level construction, its effects could happen in any order strictly, and even if you have a pure language you wind up with the `#f` issue. Strict `where` riddles your code with non-local concerns.

Comment: Could you explain how laziness helps avoid the value restriction?  I haven't been able to understand this.

Comment: Laziness has nothing to do with case expressions, pattern matching, guards or other control flow structures.  Except where there would be infinite recursion and these examples do not demonstrate that.  Also laziness does not have anything to do with the use of let or where in Haskell (Jonathan is correct).

Comment: @PaulBone What are you talking about? Laziness has a ton do to with control structures. If you define your own control structure in a strict language it is going to either have to use a bunch of lambdas or similar, or it will suck. Because `ifFunc(True, x, y)` is going to evaluate both `x` and `y` instead of just `x`.

Comment: Lazyness is not necessary to define new control structures. The Lisps distinguish for ages between syntax and procedures. Control structures are define with `define-syntax` in Scheme. The only drawback is, that if you look at an application, you do not see whether it is syntax or a procedure. You have to know, that `display` is a procedure and `define` is syntax.

Comment: Another counterexample: Koka is a strict language with algebraic effects, which are a very powerful tool for creating new control structures (they can implement exceptions, async/await, among other things).

Answer (score 75):

A useful example of lazy evaluation is the use of `quickSort`:

```
quickSort [] = []
quickSort (x:xs) = quickSort (filter (< x) xs) ++ [x] ++ quickSort (filter (>= x) xs)
```

If we now want to find the minimum of the list, we can define

```
minimum ls = head (quickSort ls)
```

Which first sorts the list and then takes the first element of the list. However, because of lazy evaluation, only the head gets computed. For example, if we take the minimum of the list `[2, 1, 3,]` quickSort will first filter out all the elements that are smaller than two. Then it does quickSort on that (returning the singleton list [1]) which is already enough. Because of lazy evaluation, the rest is never sorted, saving a lot of computational time.

This is of course a very simple example, but laziness works in the same way for programs that are very large.

There is, however, a downside to all this: it becomes harder to predict the runtime speed and memory usage of your program. This doesn't mean that lazy programs are slower or take more memory, but it's good to know.

Comment: More generally, `take k $ quicksort list` only takes O(n + k log k) time, where `n = length list`.  With a non-lazy compare sort, this would always take O(n log n) time.

Comment: @ephemient don't you mean O(n k log k) ?

Comment: @Viclib No, I meant what I said.

Comment: @ephemient then I think I don't get it, sadly

Comment: @Viclib A selection algorithm for finding the top k elements out of n is O(n + k log k).  When you implement quicksort in a lazy language, and only evaluate it far enough to determine the first k elements (stopping evaluation after), it makes the exact same comparisons as a non-lazy selection algorithm would.

Comment: @ephemient - given the pivoting strategy here, the runtime should be quadratic.

Comment: @AlexReinking you mean worst case and they mean average case. :)

Answer (score 32):

There's a difference between normal order evaluation an lazy evaluation (as in Haskell).

```
square x = x * x
```

Evaluating the following expression...

```
square (square (square 2))
```

... with eager evaluation:

```
> square (square (2 * 2))
> square (square 4)
> square (4 * 4)
> square 16
> 16 * 16
> 256
```

... with normal order evaluation:

```
> (square (square 2)) * (square (square 2))
> ((square 2) * (square 2)) * (square (square 2))
> ((2 * 2) * (square 2)) * (square (square 2))
> (4 * (square 2)) * (square (square 2))
> (4 * (2 * 2)) * (square (square 2))
> (4 * 4) * (square (square 2))
> 16 * (square (square 2))
> ...
> 256
```

... with lazy evaluation:

```
> (square (square 2)) * (square (square 2))
> ((square 2) * (square 2)) * ((square 2) * (square 2))
> ((2 * 2) * (2 * 2)) * ((2 * 2) * (2 * 2))
> (4 * 4) * (4 * 4)
> 16 * 16
> 256
```

That's because lazy evaluation looks at the syntax tree and does tree-transformations...

```
square (square (square 2))

           ||
           \/

           *
          / \
          \ /
    square (square 2)

           ||
           \/

           *
          / \
          \ /
           *
          / \
          \ /
        square 2

           ||
           \/

           *
          / \
          \ /
           *
          / \
          \ /
           *
          / \
          \ /
           2
```

... whereas normal order evaluation only does textual expansions.

That's why we, when using lazy evaluation, get more powerful (evaluation terminates more often then other strategies) while the performance is equivalent to eager evaluation (at least in O-notation).

Answer (score 27):

Lazy evaluation related to CPU the same way as garbage collection related to RAM. GC allows you to pretend that you have unlimited amount of memory and thus request as many objects in memory as you need. Runtime will automatically reclaim unusable objects. LE allows you pretending that you have unlimited computational resources - you can do as many computations as you need. Runtime just will not execute unnecessary (for given case) computations.

What is the practical advantage of these "pretending" models? It releases developer (to some extent) from managing resources and removes some boilerplate code from your sources. But more important is that you can efficiently reuse your solution in wider set of contexts.

Imagine that you have a list of numbers S and a number N. You need to find the closest to number N number M from list S. You can have two contexts: single N and some list L of Ns (e.i. for each N in L you look up the closest M in S). If you use lazy evaluation, you can sort S and apply binary search to find closest M to N. For good lazy sorting it will require O(size(S)) steps for single N and O(ln(size(S))*(size(S) + size(L))) steps for equally distributed L. If you don't have lazy evaluation to achieve the optimal efficiency you have to implement algorithm for each context.

Comment: The analogy with the GC helped me a bit, but can you give an example of "removes some boilerplate code" please?

Comment: @Abdul, an example familiar to any ORM user: lazy association loading. It loads the association from DB "just in time" and at the same time releases a developer from the need to explicitly specify when to load it and how to cache it (this is the boilerplate I mean). Here is another example: https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy.html .

Answer (score 26):

If you believe Simon Peyton Jones, lazy evaluation is not important *per se* but only as a 'hair shirt' that forced the designers to keep the language pure.   I find myself sympathetic to this point of view.

Richard Bird, John Hughes, and to a lesser extend Ralf Hinze are able to do amazing things with lazy evaluation.  Reading their work will help you appreciate it.  To good starting points are [Bird's magnificent Sudoku](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Sudoku#Sudoku_incrementally.2C_.C3.A0_la_Bird) solver and Hughes's paper on [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html).

Comment: It not just _forced them_ to keep the language pure, it also just _allowed_ them to do so, when (previous to the introduction of the `IO` monad) the signature of `main` would be `String -> String` and you could already write properly interactive programs.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: What's stopping a strict language from forcing all effects into an `IO` monad?

Answer (score 13):

Consider a tic-tac-toe program.  This has four functions:

- A move-generation function that takes a current board and generates a list of new boards each with one move applied.
- Then there is a "move tree" function which applies the move generation function to derive all the possible board positions that could follow from this one.
- There is a minimax function that walks the tree (or possibly only part of it) to find the best next move.
- There is a board-evaluation function that determines if one of the players has won.

This creates a nice clear separation of concerns.  In particular the move-generation function and the board evaluation functions are the only ones that need to understand the rules of the game: the move tree and minimax functions are completely reusable.

Now lets try implementing chess instead of tic-tac-toe.  In an "eager"  (i.e. conventional) language this won't work because the move tree won't fit in memory.  So now the board evaluation and move generation functions need to be mixed in with the move tree and minimax logic because the minimax logic has to be used to decide which moves to generate.  Our nice clean modular structure disappears.

However in a lazy language the elements of the move tree are only generated in response to demands from the minimax function: the entire move tree does not need to be generated before we let minimax loose on the top element.  So our clean modular  structure still works in a real game.

Comment: [In an "eager" (i.e. conventional) language this won't work because the move tree won't fit in memory] -- for Tic-Tac-Toe it certainly will.  There are at most 3**9 = 19683 positions to store.  If we store each one in an extravagant 50 bytes, that's almost one megabyte.  That's nothing...

Comment: Yes, thats my point.  Eager languages can have a clean structure for trivial games, but have to compromise that structure for anything real.  Lazy languages don't have that problem.

Comment: To be fair, though, lazy evaluation can lead to it's own memory issues. It's not uncommon for people to ask why haskell is blowing out it's memory for something that, in an eager evaluation, would have memory consumption of O(1)

Comment: @PaulJohnson If you evaluate all positions, it makes no difference whether you evaluate them eagerly or lazily. The same work has to be done. If you stop in the middle and evaluate only half of the positions, it also does not make any difference, because in both case half of the work has to be done. The only difference between the two evaluations is, that the algorithm looks nicer, if written lazily.

Answer (score 13):

Here are two more points which I do not believe have been brought up in the discussion yet.

1. Laziness is a synchronization mechanism in a concurrent environment. It is a lightweight and easy way to create a reference to some computation, and share its results among many threads. If multiple threads attempt to access an unevaluated value, only one of them will execute it, and the others will block accordingly, receiving the value once it becomes available.
2. Laziness is fundamental to amortizing data structures in a pure setting. This is described by Okasaki in *Purely Functional Data Structures* in detail, but the basic idea is that lazy evaluation is a controlled form of mutation critical to allowing us implement certain types of data structures efficiently. While we often speak of laziness forcing us to wear the purity hairshirt, the other way applies too: they are a pair of synergistic language features.

Answer (score 11):

When you turn on your computer and Windows refrains from opening every single directory on your hard drive in Windows Explorer and refrains from launching every single program installed on your computer, until you indicate that a certain directory is needed or a certain program is needed, that is "lazy" evaluation.

"Lazy" evaluation is performing operations when and as they are needed. It is useful when it is a feature of a programming language or library because it is generally harder to implement lazy evaluation on your own than simply to precalculate everything up front.

Comment: Some people might say that that's really "lazy execution". The difference is really immaterial except in reasonably pure languages like Haskell; but the difference is that it's not just computation being delayed, but also side effects associated with it (like opening and reading files).

Answer (score 9):

1. It can boost efficiency. This is the obvious-looking one, but it's not actually the most important. (Note also that laziness can *kill* efficiency too - this fact is not immediately obvious. However, by storing up lots of temporary results rather than calculating them immediately, you can use up a huge amount of RAM.)
2. It lets you define flow control constructs in normal user-level code, rather than it being hard-coded into the language. (E.g., Java has `for` loops; Haskell has a `for` function. Java has exception handling; Haskell has various types of exception monad. C# has `goto`; Haskell has the continuation monad...)
3. It lets you decouple the algorithm for *generating* data from the algorithm for deciding *how much* data to generate. You can write one function that generates a notionally-infinite list of results, and another function that processes as much of this list as it decides it needs. More to the point, you can have *five* generator functions and *five* consumer functions, and you can efficiently produce any combination - instead of manually coding 5 x 5 = 25 functions that combine both actions at once. (!) We all know decoupling is a good thing.
4. It more or less forces you to design a *pure* functional language. It's always tempting to take short-cuts, but in a lazy language, the slightest impurity makes your code *wildly* unpredictable, which strongly militates against taking shortcuts.

Answer (score 8):

Consider this:

```
if (conditionOne && conditionTwo) {
  doSomething();
}
```

The method doSomething() will be executed only if conditionOne is true **and** conditionTwo is true.
In the case where conditionOne is false, why do you need to compute the result of the conditionTwo? The evaluation of conditionTwo will be a waste of time in this case, especially if your condition is the result of some method process.

That's one example of the lazy evaluation interest...

Comment: I thought that was short-circuiting, not lazy evaluation.

Comment: It's lazy evaluation as conditionTwo is only calculated if it is really needed (i.e. if conditionOne is true).

Comment: I suppose short-circuiting is a degenerate case of lazy evaluation, but it's definitely not a common way to think about it.

Comment: Short Circuiting and Lazy Evaluation aren't the same.

Comment: Short-circuiting is in fact a special case of lazy evaluation. Lazy evaluation encompasses far more than just short-circuiting, obviously. Or, what does short-circuiting have over and above lazy evaluation?

Comment: -1: Short circuiting does not have the same semantics as lazy evaluation. Imagine if we called a function with two parameters, Func(conditionOne, conditionTwo), where we do not know how Func implemented or how it uses the. In C#, both conditions will be evaluated and return values passed to Func; in Haskell, neither condition is evaluated. Equivalent code in C# would be Func(() => condition1(), () = > condition2()) -- now its properly lazy.

Comment: @Juliet: You have a strong definition of 'lazy'. Your example of a function taking two parameters is not the same as a short circuit if statement. A short circuit if statement avoids unnecessary calculations. I think a better comparison to your example would be Visual Basic's operator "andalso" which forces both conditions to be evaluated

Answer (score 6):

One huge benefit of laziness is the ability to write immutable data structures with reasonable amortized bounds. A simple example is an immutable stack (using F#):

```
type 'a stack =
    | EmptyStack
    | StackNode of 'a * 'a stack

let rec append x y =
    match x with
    | EmptyStack -> y
    | StackNode(hd, tl) -> StackNode(hd, append tl y)
```

The code is reasonable, but appending two stacks x and y takes O(length of x) time in best, worst, and average cases. Appending two stacks is a monolithic operation, it touches all of the nodes in stack x.

We can re-write the data structure as a lazy stack:

```
type 'a lazyStack =
    | StackNode of Lazy<'a * 'a lazyStack>
    | EmptyStack

let rec append x y =
    match x with
    | StackNode(item) -> Node(lazy(let hd, tl = item.Force(); hd, append tl y))
    | Empty -> y
```

`lazy` works by suspending the evaluation of code in its constructor. Once evaluated using `.Force()`, the return value is cached and reused on every subsequent `.Force()`.

With the lazy version, appends are an O(1) operation: it returns 1 node and suspends the actual rebuilding of the list. When you get the head of this list, it will evaluate the contents of the node, forcing it return the head and create one suspension with the remaining elements, so taking the head of the list is an O(1) operation.

So, our lazy list is in a constant state of rebuilding, you don't pay the cost for rebuilding this list until you traverse through all of its elements. Using laziness, this list supports O(1) consing and appending. Interestingly, since we don't evaluate nodes until their accessed, its wholly possible to construct a list with potentially infinite elements.

The data structure above does not require nodes to be recomputed on each traversal, so they are distinctly different from vanilla IEnumerables in .NET.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet shows the difference between lazy and not lazy evaluation. Of course this fibonacci function could itself be optimized and use lazy evaluation instead of recursion, but that would spoil the example.

Let's suppose we *MAY* have to use the 20 first numbers for something, with not lazy evaluation all the 20 numbers have to be generated upfront, but, with lazy evaluation they'll be generated as needed only. Thus you will pay only the calculation price when needed.

Sample output

```
Not lazy generation: 0.023373
Lazy generation: 0.000009
Not lazy output: 0.000921
Lazy output: 0.024205
```

```
import time

def now(): return time.time()

def fibonacci(n): #Recursion for fibonacci (not-lazy)
 if n < 2:
  return n
 else:
  return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)

before1 = now()
notlazy = [fibonacci(x) for x in range(20)]
after1 = now()
before2 = now()
lazy = (fibonacci(x) for x in range(20))
after2 = now()


before3 = now()
for i in notlazy:
  print i
after3 = now()

before4 = now()
for i in lazy:
  print i
after4 = now()

print "Not lazy generation: %f" % (after1-before1)
print "Lazy generation: %f" % (after2-before2)
print "Not lazy output: %f" % (after3-before3)
print "Lazy output: %f" % (after4-before4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Lazy evaluation is most useful with data structures.  You can define an array or vector inductively specifying only certain points in the structure and expressing all others in terms of the whole array.  This lets you generate data structures very concisely and with high run-time performance.

To see this in action, you can have a look at my neural network library called [instinct](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/instinct).  It makes heavy use of lazy evaluation for elegance and high performance.  For example I totally get rid of the traditionally imperative activation calculation.  A simple lazy expression does everything for me.

This is used for example in the [activation function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/instinct/0.1.0/doc/html/src/AI-Instinct-Brain.html#activation) and also in the backpropagation learning algorithm (I can only post two links, so you'll need to look up the `learnPat` function in the `AI.Instinct.Train.Delta` module yourself).  Traditionally both require much more complicated iterative algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

Other people already gave all the big reasons, but I think a useful exercise to help understand why laziness matters is to try and write a [fixed-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator) function in a strict language.

In Haskell, a fixed-point function is super easy:

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

this expands to

```
f (f (f ....
```

but because Haskell is lazy, that infinite chain of computation is no problem; the evaluation is done "outside-to-inside", and everything works wonderfully:

```
fact = fix $ \f n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n-1)
```

Importantly, it matters not that `fix` be lazy, but that *`f`* be lazy. Once you've already been given an strict `f`, you can either throw your hands in the air and give up, or eta expand it and clutter stuff up. (This is a lot like what Noah was saying about it being the *library* that's strict/lazy, not the language).

Now imagine writing the same function in strict Scala:

```
def fix[A](f: A => A): A = f(fix(f))

val fact = fix[Int=>Int] { f => n =>
    if (n == 0) 1
    else n*f(n-1)
}
```

You of course get a stack overflow. If you want it to work, you need to make the `f` argument call-by-need:

```
def fix[A](f: (=>A) => A): A = f(fix(f))

def fact1(f: =>Int=>Int) = (n: Int) =>
    if (n == 0) 1
    else n*f(n-1)

val fact = fix(fact1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you currently think of things, but I find it useful to think of lazy evaluation as a library issue rather than a language feature.

I mean that in strict languages, I can implement lazy evaluation by building a few data structures, and in lazy languages (at least Haskell), I can ask for strictness when I want it. Therefore, the language choice doesn't really make your programs lazy or non-lazy, but simply affects which you get by default.

Once you think of it like that, then think of all the places where you write a data structure that you can later use to generate data (without looking at it too much before then), and you'll see a lot of uses for lazy evaluation.

Comment: Implementing lazy evaluation in strict languages is often a Turing Tarpit.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy evaluation is poor man's equational reasoning (which could be expected, ideally, to be deducing properties of code from properties of types and operations involved).

Example where it works quite well: `sum . take 10 $ [1..10000000000]`. Which we don't mind being reduced to a sum of 10 numbers, instead of just one direct and simple numeric calculation. Without the lazy evaluation of course this would create a gigantic list in memory just to use its first 10 elements. It would certainly be very slow, and might cause an out-of-memory error.

Example where it's not as great as we'd like: `sum . take 1000000 . drop 500 $ cycle [1..20]`. Which will actually sum the 1 000 000 numbers, even if in a loop instead of in a list; still it *should* be reduced to just one direct numeric calculation, with few conditionals and few formulas. Which *would* be a lot better then summing up the 1 000 000 numbers. Even if in a loop, and not in a list (i.e. after the deforestation optimization).

---

Another thing is, it makes it possible to code in [tail recursion modulo cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) style, and it *just works*.

cf. [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081318/849891).

Answer (score 2):

The most useful exploitation of lazy evaluation that I've used was a function that called a series of sub-functions in a particular order. If any one of these sub-functions failed (returned false), the calling function needed to immediately return. So I could have done it this way:

```
bool Function(void) {
  if (!SubFunction1())
    return false;
  if (!SubFunction2())
    return false;
  if (!SubFunction3())
    return false;

(etc)

  return true;
}
```

or, the more elegant solution:

```
bool Function(void) {
  if (!SubFunction1() || !SubFunction2() || !SubFunction3() || (etc) )
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Once you start using it, you'll see opportunities to use it more and more often.

Answer (score 2):

Without lazy evaluation you won't be allowed to write something like this:

```
  if( obj != null  &&  obj.Value == correctValue )
  {
    // do smth
  }
```

Comment: Well, imo, this is a bad idea to do that. While this code may be correct (depending on what you try to achieve), it's difficult to read, which is always a bad thing.

Comment: I don't think so.  Its a standard construction in C and its relatives.

Comment: This is an example of short-circuit evaluation, not lazy evaluation.  Or is that effectively the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, lazy languages allow multidimensional infinite data structures.

While scheme, python, etc allow single dimensional infinite data structures with streams, you can only traverse along one dimension.

Laziness is useful for the [same fringe problem](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SameFringeProblem), but it's worth noting the coroutines connection mentioned in that link.

Answer (score 1):

If by "lazy evaluation" you mean like in combound booleans, like in

```
   if (ConditionA && ConditionB) ...
```

then the answer is simply that the fewer CPU cycles the program consumes, the faster it will run... and if a chunk of processing instructions will have no impact on the the outcome of the program then it is unecessary, (and therefore a waste of time) to perform them anyway...

if otoh, you mean what I have known as "lazy initializers", as in:

```
class Employee
{
    private int supervisorId;
    private Employee supervisor;

    public Employee(int employeeId)
    {
        // code to call database and fetch employee record, and 
        //  populate all private data fields, EXCEPT supervisor
    }
    public Employee Supervisor
    { 
       get 
          { 
              return supervisor?? (supervisor = new Employee(supervisorId)); 
          } 
    }
}
```

Well, this technique allows client code using the class to avoid the need to call the database for the Supervisor data record except when the client using the Employee object  requires access to the supervisor's data... this makes the process of instantiating an Employee faster, and yet when you need the Supervisor, the first call to the Supervisor property will trigger the Database call and the data will be fetched and available...

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [Higher order functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions)

> Let's find the largest number under 100,000 that's divisible by 3829.
>   To do that, we'll just filter a set of possibilities in which we know
>   the solution lies.

```
largestDivisible :: (Integral a) => a  
largestDivisible = head (filter p [100000,99999..])  
    where p x = x `mod` 3829 == 0
```

> We first make a list of all numbers lower than 100,000, descending.
>   Then we filter it by our predicate and because the numbers are sorted
>   in a descending manner, the largest number that satisfies our
>   predicate is the first element of the filtered list. We didn't even
>   need to use a finite list for our starting set. That's laziness in
>   action again. Because we only end up using the head of the filtered
>   list, it doesn't matter if the filtered list is finite or infinite.
>   The evaluation stops when the first adequate solution is found.