# Lazy Quicksort in Scala

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, quicksort

Is it possible to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265392/why-is-lazy-evaluation-useful/284180#284180) sort of thing in Scala?

Comment: IMHO, a question should be self contained. Links for more details are okay, but citing two lines of haskell-code here wouldn't be too much work.

Answer (score 13):

```
def quicksort[A](xs: Stream[A])(implicit o: Ordering[A]): Stream[A] = {
  import o._ 
  if (xs.isEmpty) xs else {
      val (smaller, bigger) = xs.tail.partition(_ < xs.head)
      quicksort(smaller) #::: xs.head #:: quicksort(bigger)
  }
}
```

It can be done with views as well, though it's bound to be much slower:

```
def quicksort[A](xs: List[A])(implicit o: Ordering[A]) = {
  import o._
  def qs(xs: SeqView[A, List[A]]): SeqView[A, Seq[_]] = if (xs.isEmpty) xs else {
    val (smaller, bigger) = xs.tail.partition(_ < xs.head)
    qs(smaller) ++ (xs.head +: qs(bigger))
  }
  qs(xs.view)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to see the list-views implementation as well.

Comment: @Mahesh The view implementation turns out to be tougher than I first imagined. I'll keep trying to see if something works.

Comment: @Mahesh Ok, got the problem ironed out. I was forgetting the `.head` on the concatenation line... Silly me.

Comment: @Daniel: can we replace the first line with `quicksort[A <% Ordering[A]](xs: List[A]) = {` ?

Comment: @Aymen An `Ordering` is not as flexible as an `Ordered`. Other than that, yes, and get rid of the `import` on the second line.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think the SeqView one is lazy.  Stick a counter in there and see.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for the `#:::` operator ?

Comment: @Brian Look at the [index](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#index.index-_).

Comment: Why isn't this lazy sort (or something like it) the implementation used for `sorted`, `sortBy`, `sortWith`, etc in Stream.scala (and SeqView?).  Or is it?  Is there any way to just use library built-in functions to sort lazily?  Isn't `sorted` a "transformer?"  The documentation says Stream "implements all its transformer methods lazily," but that doesn't seem to be the case here as far as I can tell?

Comment: @Brian This isn't the implementation because no one wrote it, no one submitted it, and no one asked for it. One could argue that `sorted` is a transformer method, but I'm guessing only methods that transform _values_ are considered transformers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Scala supports "lazy vals" as a way to defer calculation of a value until it's actually used.  Much of the Scala 2.8 library is capable of working with lazily-defined collections.

Comment: this doesn't answer the asked question.